# Android: Store array of strings in shared preferences dynamically

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have only one edittext in my app from which I want to store strings array on button click. Just like history of any browser. I want to show the stored strings when my app starts. I have been trying to use shared preferences with single textview. I have attached the code for my activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button insert;
EditText edt;
TextView txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_word);

    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
    insert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
            String text = edt.getText().toString();
            editor.putString("key", text);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String text = app_preferences.getString("key", "null");
    txt1.setText(text);
}
```

}

My only one textview is populating, I want to show last five search history using this. Please give me some idea regarding this.

Comment: what is the problem exactly? "I was having problem" doesn't really help understanding what happened

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your data. Array -> String and String can be saved to the preference, maybe use JSON to encode / decode your data.
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html
http://www.json.org/